# using previous/linked value in equation

Tags: z3, z3py

It is possible to resolve this kind of equation :

```
const = [0x50, 0xe8, 0bcb, 0x9f, 0xa1]
data = IntVector('data', len(const))
for i in range(0, len(const)-1):
  s.add(data[i] >= 32, data[i] <= 126)
  s.add(data[i+1] >= 32, data[i+1] <= 126)
  s.add(data[i] + data[i+1] == const[i]
```

or I misuse Z3 library ?

Comment: Please post complete code that people can run on their own. See here for how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Yes. After fixing the obvious syntax errors, my Z3 reports it as unsatisfiable.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that `0bcb` means something like `0xcb`, then the list of constants is `[80, 232, 203, 159, 161]`.

Then you ask for 5 variables, lets call them `d0, d1, d2, d3, d4`, which are each between 32 and 126. And where `d0 + d1 == 80` (so `d1 <= 48`) and `d1 + d2 == 232` (so `d1 >= 106`). This clearly contradicts, in which Z3 agrees. (Note that your constraints don't use the last element of `const`.)

Here is a slightly more pythonic version of the code which includes each of the 5 constants (with the second constant lowered to obtain a solvable system of constraints):

```
from Z3 import IntVector, Solver, sat

const = [0x50, 0xa9, 0xcb, 0x9f, 0xa1]
s = Solver()
data = IntVector('data', len(const)+1)
for d in data:
    s.add(d >= 32, d <= 126)
for d0, d1, c0 in zip(data, data[1:], const):
    s.add(d0 + d1 == c0)
result = s.check()
if result == sat:
    print("Here is a solution: ")
    m = s.model()
    values = [m[d].as_long() for d in data]
    print(values, " sums:", [hex(v0 + v1) for v0, v1 in zip(values, values[1:])])
elif result == unsat:
    print("There is no solution")
else:
    print("Z3 could not solve the constraints")
```

Output:

```
Here is a solution: 
[37, 43, 126, 77, 82, 79]  sums: ['0x50', '0xa9', '0xcb', '0x9f', '0xa1']
```